# Erro ao tentar inserir DateTime.MinValue no banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql-server

tenho um objeto que possui uma propriedade DateTime e, inicializo com o valor da propriedade DateTime.MinValue

O problema é que, ao passar esse valor para cadastrar no banco de dados SQL Server dá um erro:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Eu entendo que o erro é porque a propriedade MinValue retorna um valor menor que o mínimo aceito pelo SQL Server, mas tem como fazer com que o valor de MinValue seja compatível com o banco de dados em uso (nesse caso SQL Server)?

ou existe outra forma melhor de inserir uma data vazia no banco?

Comment: não sei como está seu código, mas já tentou algo do tipo: cmd.Parameters["@data"].Value = d == DateTime.MinValue ? null : d.ToString();

Comment: Washington, neste caso é melhor salvar um `null` mesmo, não acha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplesmente você poderá passar um `null` ao banco como parâmetro para quando em sua variável tiver o `MinValue`.
No parâmetro, tem que converter para `Object` sua data para ficar compatível com o `DBNull.Value`.

Veja o código:

```
DateTime suaData = DateTime.MinValue;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", suaData == DateTime.MinValue ? DBNull.Value : (object)suaData);
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into TBL_data values(@data)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //exibe no console o erro
    }
}
```

*Criei essa tabela `TBL_data` como teste, nela possui um campo `date` apenas.*

Comment: nesse caso precisa mesmo converter a data para object?

Comment: Do jeito que coloquei sim, vai precisar. Se não quiser, então converta para string os dois: `DBNull.Value.ToString()` e `suaData.ToString()`